# Selecting textframes with illustrator script

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, script

How could I select textframes in illustrator with script?

Here is my code:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var nameKorText = doc.textFrames.getByName('nameKor'); 
nameKorText.contents = "test";
```

I have no idea how to make this code work.

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: The automatic name is not actually the elements name (the elements name is empty). Its just the GUI showing you something else than the name for default values. So if you want to access it by name you need to rename it or search by text contents.  Since its not clear what you want so i can not answer